# I'd like to follow the DRY principle and simplifying routing on this express server?

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have the following express server set up (server is just express() from another file).  I am sure there is a way to simplify this to only one server.get() but I haven't been able to figure out how. Any help or points in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
module.exports.api = function (server, fs) {

    server.get('/api/getData/:uuid', function (req, res) {
        fs.readFile(__dirname + '/data.json', function (err, data) {
            if (err) throw err;
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            data.forEach(function (match) {
                match['uuid'] = match['x'] + '-' + match['y'];
            });
            var match = data.filter(function (e) {
                return e.uuid == req.params.uuid
            })[0];
            res.send(200, match);
        });
    });

    server.get('/api/getData', function (req, res) {
        fs.readFile(__dirname + '/data.json', function (err, data) {
            if (err) throw err;
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            data.forEach(function (match) {
                match['uuid'] = match['x'] + '-' + match['y'];
            });
            res.send(200, data);
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: For starters, you can take all the common code and put it in a shared function that each route uses.  The copied code is much more an issue than having two route definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that just moves the common code into a shared function, yet still uses the two routes for routing clarity:

```
function getData(res, uuid) {
    fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'data.json'), function (err, fileData) {
        if (err) {
            return res.send(500);
        }
        let data = JSON.parse(fileData);
        data.forEach(function(match) {
            match['uuid'] = match['x'] + '-' + match['y'];
        });
        if (uuid) {
            var match = data.filter(function (e) {
                return e.uuid == uuid;
            })[0];
        }
        res.send(200, match);
    });
}


module.exports.api = function (server, fs) {
    server.get('/api/getData/:uuid', function (req, res) {
        getData(res, req.params.uuid);
    });

    server.get('/api/getData', function (req, res) {
        getData(res);
    });
};
```

This changes the following things:

1. Puts shared code into `getData()` function that is called from both routes.
2. Sends an error response if `fs.readFile()` has an error
3. Creates new local variable so it doesn't assign back to a function argument which is now a less desirable practice because it prevents some interpreter optimizations.
4. Uses `path.join()` to join parts of a path in a more cross platform way.

FYI, unless the data in `data.json` actually changes from time to time, you could just read this data into a variable once and then cache it rather than rereading it on every one of these requests.

---

Note: You could use routing wildcards and reduce your code to a single route, but this is mostly considered an anti-pattern because wildcards often match much more than you want, creating situations where you have manually trigger 404 errors for things you didn't intend to match that ended up matching your routing wildcard.  So, it is considered a good thing to explicitly declare the routes you intend to match rather and just share the appropriate implementation code rather than trying to collapse things down to a single route that matches more than one form of URL.

There are, of course, always exceptions by remember that the goal is clear, correct, maintainable, reliable code, not necessarily the fewest number of routes.

---

If you just want to cache the `data.json` data at server start up time, you can use `require()` to load and parse it for you like this and then there's really no reason for the sharef fucntion:

```
const cacheData = require('./data.json');
cacheData.forEach(function(match) {
    match['uuid'] = match['x'] + '-' + match['y'];
});

module.exports.api = function (server, fs) {
    server.get('/api/getData/:uuid', function (req, res) {
        let match = cacheData.filter(function (e) {
            return e.uuid == req.params.uid;
        })[0];
        res.send(match);
    });

    server.get('/api/getData', function (req, res) {
        res.send(cacheData);
    });
};
```

Comment: Great I will try this and get back to you.  The data doesn't change, that's why I really wanted to know how to store it in a variable rather than re-requesting the same data.

Comment: @OliPlunkett - I added a version that caches the data once at server startup.  Note, you can use `require()` to load and parse a `.json` file.